# How does omitting the subject affect the sentence structure?

Tags: phrases, syntactic-analysis, clauses, subordinate-clauses

I was wondering: how does the structure of this sentence change when we use the continuous form of the verb without a subject: (standing)?

"That half an hour was the peak of our social life: standing outside the door and just talking."

What would one call what I can only describe as a 'subordinate' clause?

Comment: _Standing ... door_ and _just talking_ are conjoined gerund constructions. You could call them gerund phrases, since they lack a subject and therefore are verb phrases; or you could call them reduced gerund clauses, since there is a known subject for each one, even if it doesn't appear in either. Whether you call them phrases or clauses depends on whether you are using transformations to related sentences and their constituents.

Comment: By the way, this doesn't say anything about how omitting the subject affects the sentence structure in general. There are many ways to lose subjects, and they all have different grammar, applying in different conditions.